# findViewById returns null inside handleMessage

Tags: android

Little explanation, what i want to do necessary:
I need to update UI of my activity from another thread. But from that thread not accessible non-static functions/volumes, bcs without static i can't called code from outside class by PhonePadActivity.uaReceiverHandler(msg) manner (also from that thread static reference to Activity - PhonePadActivity.phonePadActvity always null and caused exception) . But when i passed in for using static handler, all static references also always null, which not gives me possibility to update UI (simple findViewByID product compiler error can't reference static method from non-static). So, only PhonePadActivity.uaReceiverHandler(msg) from another thread working, can change local private static variables, but can't access to view objects) How i can solve it?

i'm receive well message by handle message:

```
public static final Handler uaReceiverHandler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();
        Log.e(THIS_FILE, "WAS regState" + regState);
        regState = b.getString("regState");  
        TextView statusLocal = (TextView) phonePadForUsing.findViewById(R.id.registrationStatus);

        statusLocal.setText("Registered");

    }
};
```

in my case:

```
public  class PhonePadActivity extends Activity {
      public static PhonePadActivity phonePadForUsing;
      private static TextView status;
```

which assigned:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_pad);
    phonePadForUsing = this;
    status = ((TextView) phonePadForUsing.findViewById(R.id.registrationStatus));
```

This code working fine, regState is assigned as well, but phonePadForUsing always return null exemption, this code:

```
        status.setText("Registered");
```

return full trace:

> 10-05 13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-05 13:34:51.495:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12744):  at
>   com.callsfreecalls.android.PhonePadActivity$4.handleMessage(PhonePadActivity.java:1180)
>   10-05 13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-05
>   13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 10-05 13:34:51.495:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12744):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 10-05
>   13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-05
>   13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-05 13:34:51.495:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12744):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-05 13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-05
>   13:34:51.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12744):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

onCreate was fired before, so, all elements is already done, bcs i have log in OnCreate (as u see, it 10 seconds early than exception...:

> 10-05 13:34:41.535: D/PhonePad(12735): onCreate: created

Any suggestion will appreciated, please include peace of code as well. Same code working well from another Handler which using from another class:

```
final static Handler clientControllerHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final TextView status = ((TextView) phonePadForUsing.findViewById(R.id.registrationStatus));
        status.setText("Data not received");
```

Comment: NEVER EVER reference your activity's instance to a STATIC object. Its really a bad practice.

Comment: @Waqas if i don't using static i can't access to UI from hangerMessage. any suggestion? i have error can't make static reference to non-static method )

Comment: your class is seriously more than 1180 lines long ?

Comment: @njzk2 yep :) i hope it's not compiler error :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so firstly, go by the method which works. Usually all UI elements are initialized in onCreate(). Then access it in your Handler.

```
public static final Handler uaReceiverHandler = new Handler(){  

@Override  
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
    Bundle b = msg.getData();  
    Log.e(THIS_FILE, "WAS regState" + regState);  
    regState = b.getString("regState");   
    //More this to onCreate(), make statusLocal a global variable.
    TextView statusLocal = (TextView) phonePadForUsing.findViewById(R.id.registrationStatus);  

    statusLocal.setText("Registered");  

}  };
```

Comment: i guess u are wrong, i'm update question and u can see that onCreate was fired before. Any another suggestion?

Comment: Remove the registration from the Handler. No need to register same thing twice.

Comment: i'm very new in android, please, some peace of code will appreciated. Where is registration removing and how?

Comment: Remove --> TextView statusLocal = (TextView) phonePadForUsing.findViewById(R.id.registrationStatus); from the Handler. Delete that line

Comment: i was leave only status.setText("Registered"), but i have same null pointer exception....

Comment: Help me understand why you need a handler at all? You can do it without and you will not face this problem!

Comment: @Ryston Pinto problem very simple. i have updates, which received from c library and upcoming to classes, which handle those updates. i need update UI according those updates. that why i need handler. if u can suggest another way, please describe.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your stacktract:

PhonePadActivity.java:1180

throws null pointer exception - this means that variable you are dereferencing is not initialized  or null.

and careful Looking in you code reveals that handler is static class - thus it has no refernce to  original instance - so your reference may as well be null even if you initialized it.

Just add log statement before this invocation so you can see what happens.

Comment: yep, i know that. A problem is a same code, called from another class, working fine. But same code called from another thread is not working. How i can change it code?

Comment: please read my explanation. i'm sure that variable initialized bcs same variable from another class non-null (difference is just static/non static handler reference type. Any suggestion? maybe how i can initialize and access in future without null caused?